# Why system go to suspend not power off?

Tags: power-management

When I press the power button on a machine, I got log:

```
PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
```

Is it suspending? not powering off?

which setting can change it?

Comment: Windows 10 ? If so shutting it down normally suspends or rather hibernates: https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

Comment: Redhat 8, linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using systemd, the power button effect is now determined by
[logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html). You can create an override in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
[Login]
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
```

Comment: this seems not to work for graphic mode. ( GNOME)

Comment: The Redhat documentation for setting poweroff for gnome is [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/customizing-gnome-desktop-features_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8#changing-behavior-when-pressing-the-powerbutton_customizing-gnome-desktop-features).

Comment: it seems we can not do power off by pressing the power button in GNOME now (Redhat 8)?